# Is there way to specify browser(user) from server?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have clients(A, B) and they use my service.
They have domains and they include same javascript to their websites.
The javascript communicates with my server and saves cookies to the domain.
The cookies are the infomation about a connected user and cookies are different by user.
I assume they use same browser.

So if a user connect to A website and connect to B website, I want to save same key information to their cookies.

Is their way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access cookies for other domains, but you can set up a third domain `tracking.example`, and then request any resource (e.g. a 1pixel image) from that domain.

To read the cookie from one of the websites, either use a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)-enabled endpoint, e.g. `https://tracking.example/getuserid`, that allows client-side code on the website to read out the cookie or an ID that is associated with it, or embed an iframe from `tracking.example` and use [inter-frame-communication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Note that for privacy reasons, third-party cookies are being restricted, or even totally blocked by [some browsers](https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/) and [configurations](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies). There is no replacement for third-party cookies, while there are [ways to identify users without cookies](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), they are nowhere near 100% accurate, may violate local laws, and are intended to be by browsers.

If both websites manage logins, you can of course use the logged-in email address as an ID.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an iframe, any request should suffice.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! The iframe is indeed only necessary if we want to communicate between frames.